# Keeping Two Git Repositories Synced?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a situation where I have two repositories, one for the free version of a package, and another for a pro version.

The free functionality I'd like to be synced between the two somehow. The pro functionality I'd like to remain in the pro repository.

What would be the easiest and cleanest way of doing this?

I thought about adding the free repo as another remote of the pro, but as far as I know I can't do a conditional push, leaving out the pro functionality.

Comment: have you looked at submodules?

Comment: This isn't really a thing git can neatly solve for you. The way to solve this is to modularize the functionality into libraries or whatever makes sense in your project, and either include it or not when you build the two distributions.

Comment: Why go with submodules? I'd use 2 branches and 2 remotes where I'd keep each of the branches separately (using a single local repo to do the whole thing).

Comment: As Dan suggested I'd recommend making a change to the architecture of your project, so you can 'depend upon' the free version and extend it's feature set in the 'pro version'. Most languages have a package manager which will allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to add part of files/code of pro repo to free version repo. You can use **git subtree**, detail steps as below:

1. In pro repo, create a branch (such as `ForFree`) and make changes to make sure the files/code is the version you want to add to free version repo.
2. In free version repo, you can add the `ForFree` branch of pro repo to free version repo by `git subtree add --prefix=pro <URL for pro repo> ForFree`.
3. Now you have a folder named `pro` which only contain the files you want to add in free version repo.
4. If the `ForFree` branch in pro repo is updated, you can sync in your free version repo by `git subtree pull --prefix=pro <URL for pro repo> ForFree`.
5. If you make changes in `pro` folder of local free version repo and you want to push the changes to pro repo `ForFree` branch, you can use `git subtree push --prefix=pro <URL for pro repo> ForFree`.